# Spark Scala MLlib assignment syntax

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I've been going through the guide at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-statistics.html and I've noticed that they're using this syntax for val assignment:

```
val Row(coeff1: Matrix) = Correlation.corr(df, "features").head
```

Can someone elaborate on what this means? It seems similar to how Scala handles regex group extraction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is nothing more than a [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html). To make it more obvious, you rewrite it as:

```
val coeff1 = Correlation.corr(df, "features").head match {
  case Row(coeff1: Matrix) => coeff1
}
```

In other words it just tries to match the object returned form `.head` call and on successful match, it creates a reference (`coeff1`) to the `Matrix` object contained in the returned `Row`.

Comment: Is this specific of this labrary, or a general obscure feature of Pattern matching overall?